# How to tokenize italian input?

Tags: java, nlp, tokenize

I'm trying to tokenize italian text for further processing, in Java.
Is there any tool that for tokenizing italian input?
A [SimpleTokenizer](http://code.google.com/p/tt4j/wiki/SimpleTokenizer) works fine a certain extent, but then in case like Italian family names like "De Marchi" I get it as 2 tokens.

Comment: How does your input look like?

Comment: Getting the extent of names right is generally considered named entity recognition, not tokenization, so it's unlikely that any off-the-shelf tokenizer will do this for you.

Comment: I second larsmans comment; take a look at the http://gate.ac.uk toolbox for bundled parsers, tokenizers and IE tools.